# Clone Google spreadsheet using Google sheets V4 and give access to teammates

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm Using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 from my Java project and accessing it using service account. I'm trying to duplicate a spreadsheet to create new one with the same data and different spreadsheet id using V4 API but I couldn't. Is it possible to do so?

And how to add new gmail user to access already existing sheet using Google V4 sheets API?

```
{
    "role":"editor",
    "type":"user",
    "emailAddress":mohammed_kamal@gmail.com
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the permissions cannot be added by Sheets API. In this case, you can addo them by the method of "Permissions: create" in Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on **copying only a sheet**, **Sheets API** is the right choice in this case **but** if you want to **copy the whole spreadsheet**, you need to make use of **Drive API**'s [copy file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) method. You can replicate the behavior by using the below request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/copy
```

As for creating the permissions to the already existing spreadsheet by adding new users, you need to make use of Drive API as well and use the request below:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions
```

With the following body:

```
{
    "role":"editor",
    "type":"user",
    "emailAddress":mohammed_kamal@gmail.com
}
```

#### Note

In both of these requests, the `fileId` here corresponds to the `id` of the spreadsheet wanted to make a copy of.

#### Reference

- [Sheets API spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo);
- [Drive API Files:copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy);
- [Drive API Permissions:create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions).